# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, stack-overflow

I have a piece of code and I could not figure out why it is giving me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.

This is the question:

```
Given a positive integer n, prints out the sum of the lengths of the Syracuse 
sequence starting in the range of 1 to n inclusive. So, for example, the call:
lengths(3)
will return the the combined length of the sequences:
1
2 1
3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 
which is the value: 11. lengths must throw an IllegalArgumentException if 
its input value is less than one.
```

My Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

HashMap<Integer,Integer> syraSumHashTable = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

public Test(){

}

public int lengths(int n)throws IllegalArgumentException{

    int sum =0;

    if(n < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error!! Invalid Input!");
    }   

    else{


        for(int i =1; i<=n;i++){

            if(syraSumHashTable.get(i)==null)
            {
                syraSumHashTable.put(i, printSyra(i,1));
                sum += (Integer)syraSumHashTable.get(i);

            }

            else{

                sum += (Integer)syraSumHashTable.get(i);
            }



        }

        return sum;

    }



}

private int printSyra(int num, int count){

    int n = num;

    if(n == 1){

        return count;
    }

    else{   
            if(n%2==0){

                return printSyra(n/2, ++count);
            }

            else{

                return printSyra((n*3)+1, ++count) ;

            }

    }


}
}
```

Driver code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test s1 = new Test();
    System.out.println(s1.lengths(90090249));
    //System.out.println(s1.lengths(5));
}
```

. 
I know the problem lies with the recursion. The error does not occur if the input is a small value, example: 5. But when the number is huge, like 90090249, I got the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. Thanks all for your help. :)

I almost forgot the error msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:65)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:65)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
at Test.printSyra(Test.java:60)
```

Comment: Most likely integer overflow. Use long instead. (And there is no need to use recursion here, although if implement correctly, there should be no StackOverflow error for certain range of number).

Comment: I don't actually see a recursion here?? Are you hiding something??  where is your `printSyra(i,1)` method?

Comment: @RohitJain `printSyra` invokes `printSyra`

Comment: @Pshemo.. How can you assume that?? Its not there..

Comment: @RohitJain check returns of `printSyra` method.

Comment: Ah. Sorry.. Scrollbar didn't come out.. Needed to refresh window..  :(

Comment: Sorry guys. I was updating the post to add more info. Thanks for viewing. I think the recursion is fine? I am still not sure why the error is happening.

Comment: If its actually the stack overflowing you could try tweaking the jvm with the xss option for instance. If its integer overflow just do as @nhahtdh suggests :)

Comment: Use long/BigInt and you should be fine. Its because of small range of int

Comment: It looks like case of intergeroverflow which in turns as per the algo results in stackoverflow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine. However `int` is too small for your computations, it fails for this input:

```
printSyra(113383, 1);
```

At some point integer overflows to negative value and your implementation goes crazy, recursing infinitely. Change `int num` to `long num` and you'll be fine - for some time. Later you'll need `BigInteger`.

Note that according to Wikipedia on [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) (bold mine):

> The longest progression for any initial starting number less than 100 million is 63,728,127, which has **949 steps**. For starting numbers less than 1 billion it is 670,617,279, with 986 steps, and for numbers less than 10 billion it is 9,780,657,630, with **1132 steps**.

The total number of steps is equivalent to maximum nesting level (stack depth) you can expect. So even for relatively big numbers `StackOverflowError` should not occur. Have a look at this implementation using `BigInteger`:

```
private static int printSyra(BigInteger num, int count) {
    if (num.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        return count;
    }
    if (num.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return printSyra(num.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)), count + 1);
    } else {
        return printSyra(num.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3)).add(BigInteger.ONE), count + 1);
    }
}
```

It works even for very big values:

```
printSyra(new BigInteger("9780657630"), 0)  //1132
printSyra(new BigInteger("104899295810901231"), 0)  //2254
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused myself, here - I thought that stack overflows generally occur when the relatively small stack (where function state is stored) runs out of memory after too many recursive calls, not because of some integer being too large. Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer? I do agree that using int instead of long is probably the real cause of OP's problem, but it's still possible to recurse deeply enough to cause a stack overflow regardless of how large you can make the input number.

Comment: @Tomasz: Thanks. I have changed int num to long num and now I faces another error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:462)
 at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:755)
 at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
 at Test.lengths(Test.java:26)
 at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:10)

Comment: My main issue with this answer: Technically correct, but misleading. A better solution is to avoid recursion entirely (See @greyfairer's answer). In fact, you should avoid recursion in most cases (in Java), without a very good reason.

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua: Why do you store in the HashMap in the first place, if you don't use it? You can use it to speed up the calculation in `printSyra`.

Comment: @Kiyura: I wrote: "*[...]integer overflows [...] and your implementation goes crazy, recursing infinitely*" - the reason this implementation fails is not because of too deep recursion (it's never that deep, as Wikipedia says), but because of integer overflow - that causes abnormally deep recursion. When implementation is correct, `StackOverflowError` is not a problem. But you are right, without tail recursion optimization this implementation is still a bit inefficient - but very clear from readability perspective.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: i called the method from my for loop and I get a Java error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:557)
 at Test.lengths(Test.java:28)
 at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:10)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Seems like the for loop is not happy in calling so many recursions? How do overcome this? :)

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua: please open another question, comments aren't good for posting code and solving problems.

Comment: @nhatdh: How can I use it to speed it up?

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua: Near the end, your HashMap will store around 100 **million** elements. Do you even need it? As for speeding up, you can return value early in printSyra if you have encountered an element that you have calculated before using the HashMap.

Comment: @nhahtdh: +1, this is called [*memoization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and it will seriously speed up this algorithm. It'll be even faster than a version with loop if used several times.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes!! I am suppose to implement it. How can I check if the element is calculated before? Am I not suppose to use a for loop to keep track of the elements in the HashMap?

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua: Try first, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent problem with recursive algorithms. Make the number of recursions large enough and you can't really avoid a stack overflow, unless the language can guarantee tail-call optimization (Java and most C-like languages don't). The only way to truly fix it is to "unroll" the recursion, rewriting the algorithm iteratively or with a helper function to simulate the state-passing of the recursive call without actually nesting calls.

Comment: Not sure why downvote.. am I missing something? Please comment if you downvote.

Comment: Recursion is fine here. Real problem is with integer overflow.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? [Documentation for java.lang.StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html): Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Comment: I'm sure, because I know what the OP is doing in `printSyra`. There should be enough stack for a few hundred levels.

Comment: @nhahtdh, so how can i fix this if it is an intger overflow?

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua: Use long instead of int. I'm not too sure it will work for all, but up to some range, it should be able to contain all numbers in the chain.

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua Best solution would be implementing it without recursion (this way you get rid of StackOverflow error). Also since you cant know Maximum number that will be generated while counting 3x+1 avoid integer and use something bigger `long` or maybe BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to allow the JVM to take more space for stack recursion, using the java -Xss parameter. Its default is less than a megabyte, IIRC, which could limit to a couple of hundred recursions max.

A better solution is to rewrite the exercise without recursion:

```
private int printSyra(int num){
    int count = 1;    
    int n = num;    
    while(n != 1){

            if(n%2==0){    
                n = n/2;
                ++count;
            }    
            else{    
                n=(n*3)+1;
                ++count;    
            }    
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: My implementation with recursion can run with N = 104899295810901231 which has length of 2254 (http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/delrecs.html). While I agree that recursion may be a problem, the intermediate numbers can overflow the range of integer way before the recursion problem kicks in.

Comment: Your version still fails to compute for numbers as small as `113383` - but instead of throwing `StackOverflowException`, goes into an infinite loop. Moreover increasing the stack size won't help for broken algorithm (wrong variable type).